# Lua script fails but the JS works in console

Tags: lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have this very basic lua script that returns an error, but running the querySelector directly in the console works just fine.

Any hints on what is wrong with my lua?

```
function main(splash, args)
      assert(splash:go(args.url))
      assert(splash:wait(1))
      assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-show-rates").click()'))
      splash:set_viewport_full()
      return {
        html = splash:html(),
      }
    end
```

BTW: [website is here](https://www.thebookingbutton.co.uk/properties/GENERALHOTELLDIRECT?check_in_date=15-01-2019&check_out_date=16-01-2019&number_adults=1)

Error log:

```
{
"type": "ScriptError",
"error": 400,
"info": {
    "type": "LUA_ERROR",
    "line_number": 4,
    "error": "JS error: 'TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating \\'document.querySelector(\"button.btn.btn-primary.btn-show-rates\").click\\')'",
    "message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]:4: JS error: 'TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating \\'document.querySelector(\"button.btn.btn-primary.btn-show-rates\").click\\')'",
    "source": "[string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]"
},
"description": "Error happened while executing Lua script"
 }
```

Comment: Oh. And any smart tips on how to press all three buttons would be usefull too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was kinda simple...

A slightly longer "wait" and changing to document.querySelectorAll made it work. Final code here:

```
    function main(splash, args)
      assert(splash:go(args.url))
      assert(splash:wait(5.0))
      assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelectorAll("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-show-rates")[0].click()'))
      assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelectorAll("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-show-rates")[1].click()'))
      assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelectorAll("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-show-rates")[2].click()'))
      splash:set_viewport_full()
      return {
        html = splash:html(),
      }
    end
```